# Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS. I don't have the access to server

Tags: angular, api, cors

I am tryingto consume a public API, but I have a failure answer. I tested with Postman and with browsers (like google chrome and microsoft edge), and I can consume the API, but when I tried to consume the API with my angular app, I don't have a successfully answer

The answer is:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bio.torre.co/api/bios/ricovar96?s=fMoC3WTE0B' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I dont have access to the server, because is a public API, so I cannot put @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200"). This is the error:

[image]

and this is the url API: https://bio.torre.co/api/bios/ricovar96?s=fMoC3WTE0B

I made this step but didn't work:

1. Create a proxy.conf.json file in the same level of package.json whit this strucuture:

> ```
> {
>     "*/api/*":{
>         "target": "https://bio.torre.co",
>         "secure": false,
>         "changeOrigin": true,
>         "logLevel": "debug",
>         "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
>     }
> }
> ```

2. I Modified the package.json. I added the file I created in the script section like this:

> "scripts": {
> ...
> "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", ... }

3. I modified the Service I created like this (in the app.module.ts I set in the imports the HTTPClientModule ):

> ```
> import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
>
> @Injectable({
>   providedIn: 'root'
> })
> export class ResumeService {
> >     
>   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
>
>   getUserData(id: string): Observable<any> {
>     return this.http.get<any>(api/bios/ricovar96?s=fMoC3WTE0B");
>   }
> }
> ```

4. I ran npm start.

But I got this answer:

[image]

What do you think It is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue creating an API in .Net. This API consumed the API that has the error CORS, but with this settings in Configure Method in .Net

> ```
>         app.UseCors(x=>x
>             .AllowAnyOrigin()
>             .AllowAnyMethod()
>             .AllowAnyHeader());
> ```

After that I published this API in Azure. If you have access to backend added this configuration, if you not, try to contact with IT department and try to add this configuration. If you have other solution, please leave in the comment

Comment: Did you create a api to consume other api?